# Find location of checked out svn repository

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am trying to write a bash script that creates shortcuts to specific folders on a repository. The problem is that I want to run it on computers other than my own, but the location of the checked out location of this repository varies based on the computer. Is there a way to find out where that is for each computer.

Windows 7 Pro

TortoiseSVN 1.7.10, Build 23359 - 64 Bit , 2012/10/08 11:46:26

Subversion 1.7.7,

Answer (score 0):

You could create custom environment variable such as MY_SVN_PROJECT_DIRECTORY on Windows 7 by right-clicking on computer, clicking on "Advanced system settings" and choosing "Environment Variables" button on the resulting dialog.  Then have your bash script check the value of that variable when creating shortcuts.